# .NET project tracked with git - keeping target Framework 4.0 and 4.5.2 in parallel

Tags: .net, git, asp.net

Relatively new git user here, so just trying to figure out the best way to keep my project as 4.0 and 4.5.2 framework variants in parallel. Maybe this shouldn't even be done within git? Just create a completely new/separate project that uses the 4.5.2 framework as the target and start a brand new repository?

Thoughts? Is git the right tool for this?

Comment: Where do you see the problems with simply updating the project and committing the changes?

Comment: There will be multiple installations using the same code base. Some of the installations will not be updated to the new framework, but still may need to be supported, so I'd like to keep the prior project.

Comment: If you need to support v4 of the framework, you should continue targeting v4 of the framework. You should ***not*** fork your code base. If you *really* feel compelled to do this, then you should conditionally compile for both targets.

Comment: Understood. Unfortunately, I need to add some functionality that will require 4.5.2 because I'll be using a 3rd party library. Want to leave a copy of the v4 project that can still be used/accessed if needed, but will primarily be using/maintaining the 4.5.2 version.

Comment: I took the freedom and edited your question to match what you wrote here in the comments, the former question text asked for something very different. Updating from 4.0 to 4.5.2 is something you do obviously do using Visual Studio or a text editor, not with a VCS.

Comment: Ahh okay. I see what you're asking now.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on if you want to keep the old 4.0 version in Git (almost) frozen, and only apply fixes to severe bugs to that older version (hopefully seldom), or if you want to evolve both the 4.0 and 4.5.2 version in parallel.

For the first scenario, you can attach a tag to the 4.0 version's source code, so in case you need to add a bug fix to that line of development, you can find it easily in the version history and transfer or down-port bugfixes from the main 4.5.2 development line into that 4.0 branch. For the second scenario, I recommend to follow @RubberDuck's comment: don't fork, instead adjust your build configuration to compile to both targets from essentially the same source code.

Comment: I think the first scenario is going to be the route I have to go. The 4.0 version will remain active/supported, but there is a need to use 4.5.2 in order to add in a 3rd party library that not all clients will need.

Answer (score 1):

Given your previous comments i am assuming that the 4.0 Version will be not developed in parallel to the 4.5.2 version.

In your position i would create a separate branch for the 4.0 version because if you happen to develop something in the main branch that will be needed in the 4.0 branch you can just switch branches and cherry pick the commit(s).